# What does /usr/sbin/install really do?

Tags: makefile, installation, discount

I'm trying to install [discount](https://github.com/Orc/discount) on my [VPS](http://no.de) which is based on Solaris and compiling works great after setting some environment variables but the [install fails](https://gist.github.com/1951ab6c2089b7ef091f).

So I thought I'd do the install manually, but what does `install` really do? Is it simply a `mv` followed by a `chmod`? Is it magic? That error seems to show that it attempts to do a lot of searching for files all over?

Can I just copy the binary, library and header files as usual?

Googling "install" doesn't give me much relevant information so I appreciate any clarification I can get!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [`man install`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?install):

> ```
> install [OPTION]... [-T] SOURCE DEST`  
> install [OPTION]... SOURCE... DIRECTORY  
> install [OPTION]... -t DIRECTORY SOURCE...  
> install [OPTION]... -d DIRECTORY...
> ```
>
> In  the first three forms, copy SOURCE to DEST or multiple SOURCE(s) to
>         the existing DIRECTORY, while setting permission modes and owner/group.
>         In the 4th form, create all components of the given DIRECTORY(ies).

As for the difference to using `cp`, according to [install vs. cp; and mmap](http://en.chys.info/2009/05/install-vs-cp-and-mmap/), `install` unlinks the existing file, creating a new one linked to the same spot.

This has the advantage that, if the file you're trying to overwrite is a currently running program, it can continue running, as the file being written is in fact in a new location, and the existing program code is still in the old one.

A `cp` simply tries to overwrite the existing file, which will fail if the file is locked due to being in use.

#### Further information

- [install Command](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.cmds/doc/aixcmds3/install.htm)

Comment: Yes, well that's how to use it. But what does it really do? Like, behind the scenes. If it only copies a file, why wouldn't the Makefile just use `cp`?

Comment: I just added a link to [install vs. cp; and mmap](http://en.chys.info/2009/05/install-vs-cp-and-mmap/), which may answer your questions about that.

Comment: So `install` is basically a work-around for the fact that BSD doesn't support GNU's `cp --remove-destination`.